# Authorization header not added properly

Tags: angular, header, jwt, angular7

I'm working with JWTs and successfully made an Express app that handels them well, verified using Postman. I then went to do the Angular 7 frontend, and I stumbled upon a problem. I add the headers successfully, but they don't seem to appear on the actual request:

I log the headers, and can see they are set:

[image]

But when I look at the request, it doesn't appear:

[image]

My code looks like this:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {

  private baseUrl = environment.apiUrl;

  constructor(private http: Http,
              private auth: AuthService) { }

  get(url: string) {
    return this.request(url, RequestMethod.Get);
  }

  post(url: string, body: Object) {
    return this.request(url, RequestMethod.Post, body);
  }

  put(url: string, body: Object) {
    return this.request(url, RequestMethod.Put, body);
  }

  delete(url: string) {
    return this.request(url, RequestMethod.Delete);
  }

  request(url: string, method: RequestMethod, body?: Object) {
  let headers = new Headers()
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  headers.append('Authorization', `Bearer ${this.auth.getToken()}`);

  console.log(headers);

  const requestOptions = new RequestOptions({
    url: `${this.baseUrl}/${url}`,
    method: method,
    headers: headers
  });

  if (body) {
    requestOptions.body = body;
  }

  const request = new Request(requestOptions);

  return this.http.request(request)
    .pipe(map((res: Response) => res.json()))
    .pipe(catchError((res: Response) => this.onRequestError(res)));
}

onRequestError(res: Response) {
  const statusCode = res.status;
  const body = res.json();


  const error = {
    statusCode: statusCode,
    error: body.error
  };

  console.log(error);

  return observaleThrowError(error || "Server error");
}
}
```

LoginComponent:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  email: string;

  constructor(public api: ApiService,
    private auth: AuthService,
    private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    const values = form.value;

    const payload = {
      username: values.username,
      password: values.password
    }

    this.api.post('authenticate', payload).subscribe(data => {
      this.auth.setToken(data.token);
      this.router.navigate(['/contacts']);
    })
  }
}
```

Again it works all fine and dandy with Postman. Any idea on what goes wrong?

Comment: Just             headers.append('Authorization', token); would suffice

Comment: Does Angular add "Bearer" by itself?

Comment: I meant headers.append('Authorization', `Bearer ${this.auth.getToken()}`); in your case

Comment: But I need to have the backticks to call the function?

Comment: DId you implement cors on your backend if needed? Specifically `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization`

Comment: @David My backend handles it all well.

Comment: Can you show the headers for the OPTIONS request and response?

Answer (score 0):

For JWT authentication in Angular app i suggest you to use interceptors.

You define your interceptor like this:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class JwtInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
     intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
     // add authorization header with jwt token if available
     const currentUser = JSON.parse(String(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')));
     if (currentUser && currentUser.Token) {
         request = request.clone({
         setHeaders: {
             Authorization: `Bearer ${currentUser.Token}`
         }
      });
      }
      return next.handle(request);
   }
}
```

Basically, what it does, It uses the JWT Token stored in your clients localStorage and sends it with every HTTP request to your backend.

Then you just have to register it in you `app.module.ts`

```
providers: [
  HttpClient,
  {
     provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
     useClass: JwtInterceptor,
     multi: true
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into that. Do you think it'll solve my problem?

Comment: I'm sure it will. In case of trouble use this [link](https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors-2f9d1540eb8)

Comment: Cool! Do you see anything wrong with my code as it is now?

Comment: Try creating your headers like this: ```const headers = new HttpHeaders({'Authorization': 'Bearer ${this.auth.getToken()}'});``` and send them with: ```this.httpClient.post<any>(this.baseUrl + route, params, {headers: headers});```